# Import Certificates to Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacert

Tags: terminal

I cannot seem to be able to -importcert as when I run command below it says 
Illegal option:  –keystore

```
$ sudo keytool -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -importcert -alias rootca -file "$DOWNLOAD_LOCATION/file"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call keytool with the to be executed action as first argument:

```
sudo keytool -importcert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts" ...
```

Comment: the certificates were only able to be used with an older version of JDK

Comment: @ChrisLinder I don't get your comment. Have you been able to import successfully? I doubt, that the JDK version has any impact on the validity of certificates.

Comment: Yes. I was able to import and the certificate owners stated as such.